# Spring Cancel @Async Task

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I want to be able to cancel a method marked with the `@Async` annotation by it's future.

I have a Spring method marked with the `@Async` annotation. This method does some computation, and eventually returns a result. All examples I have seen recommend using the `AsyncResult` class to return this Future.

```
@Async
public Future<String> run() {
    // ... Computation. Minutes pass ...
    return new AsyncResult<String>("Result");
}
```

I call the following method, from another Component, in the following manner. For example purposes, I wish to immediately cancel this thread:

```
Future<String> future = component.run();
future.cancel(true);
```

In this case, the thread will never be cancelled. This is because, looking at the Spring implementation for `AsyncResult` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncResult.java#L71 , this method doesn't actually do a single thing. It simply returns false, that the thread could not be cancelled. This is my problem. How can I cancel the Thread being created by the `@Async` method? I have no access to the internal thread being created by Spring - so I have no means myself with which to cancel it, do I?

Comment: check those 2 answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084195/spring-async-cancel-and-start) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798987/stop-an-async-spring-method-from-caller-class) , or else create a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` to handle the `@Async` annotated methods or pass a custom `AsyncResult` which will bind with the running task.

Comment: The answers in those questions seem to describe creating some flag/semaphore in order to tell the running thread to stop processing at a later point. This is different than terminating a thread as the Future.cancel() method would do in a self defined `Runnable`. 

Can you explain a bit further what a custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` would look like? I also define my own Executor, so adding to it would not be difficult or inconvenient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, Spring `@Async` uses a background thread pool of it's own. And as long as cancel() method of Future or shutdownNow() of executor service is concerned, Calling `executor.shutdownNow() or future.cancel(true)` don’t stop the ongoing thread immediately. What these methods do is simply call `.interrupt()` on the respective thread(s). And `interrupts` has **no guaranteed immediate** effect. It issues a flag so whenever in sleeping or waiting state, the thread will be stopped.

To be noted, If your tasks ignore the interruption, `executor.shutdownNow() and future.cancel(true)` will behave exactly the same way as `executor.shutdown() and future.cancel(false)`.

If you need a way to stop the slow or blocking operation. If you have a long/endless loop, you can just add a condition whether `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` and don’t continue if it is true(end the operation).

Comment: Great. I added boolean checks for `Thread.interrupted()` throughout my `@Async` method's logic; and if I detect the interrupt, I can safely tear down the method and cancel execution.

Comment: Hi Prateek. Can you please provide a source for your answer?

Comment: what happens if all the threads in the pool are leaked, and it ends up empty?

Comment: @PatrickD facing same issue.. Can you have look at the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708378/gracefully-terminating-existing-async-thread-in-spring-boot