# what happens when a Spring @Async thread never completes?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, java-11, java.util.concurrent, spring-async

If you have an @Async method the returns a `CompletableFuture`....and the future *never* gets completed, does spring just leak the thread?  Yes, I know whomever is waiting on the results could timeout and *assume* exceptional completion for latter stages.....but that doesn't stop the thread.  Even if you call `cancel`, it doesn't do shit to the running thread:

from the docs:

> @param mayInterruptIfRunning this value has no effect in this
> implementation because interrupts are not used to control
> processing.

If I use Future instead of CompletableFuture, `cancel` will interrupt the thread.  Unfortunately, there is no equivalent of "allOf" on Future like we have on CompletableFuture to wait for all the tasks, like so:

```
// wait for all the futures to finish, regardless of results
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))
   // if exceptions happened in any future, swallow them
   // I don't care because I'm going to process each future in my list anyway
   // we just wanted to wait for all the futures to finish
   .exceptionally(ex -> null);
```

1. how are we supposed to cancel a thread that we bailed on?
2. if I didn't cancel it (somehow), would my pool just be down a thread forever????

Comment: would `.orTimeOut()` solve your problem? It would either complete or throw a TimeOut Exception. So if the thread is abandoned, the future would eventually timeout. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: not really....that still just bails on the CompletableFuture so the caller can move on....the thread of execution just keeps on chugging....

Comment: Ah...misunderstood your intent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Cancel @Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880069/spring-cancel-async-task)

Comment: I guess....I mean, it basically says "no, you can't".  I'm still stunned that the springs docs don't seem to explicitly _tell_ you what happens if all the threads in the pool get leaked....or provide a clean / simple leak detection mechanism.

Comment: there isn't, yes. But it's not Spring to be blamed, it's the fact that a `CompletableFuture` can not be canceled, [without stopping the executor itself and hoping that the task responds to interrupts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64743332/stopping-a-thread-in-java-completablefuture-after-timeout/64815403#64815403)