# Stopping a thread in java CompletableFuture after timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, completable-future

I have an async chain in my java code that i want to stop after a certain timeout
so i created a threadPool with some threads and called the CompletableFuture like this

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

than i have a cyclic method that loads data from the db and executes some task on it, once all the CompletableFutures are completed its doing it again

```
CompletableFuture<MyObject> futureTask =
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> candidate, pool)
                .thenApply(Task1::doWork).thenApply(Task2::doWork).thenApply(Task3::doWork)
                .thenApply(Task4::doWork).thenApply(Task5::doWork).orTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .thenApply(Task6::doWork).orTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .exceptionally(ExceptionHandlerService::handle);
```

My problem is in **task6**, that has a very intensive task (its a network connection task that sometimes hangs forever)
i noticed that my orTimeout is being fired correctly after 30 seconds, but the thread running Task6 is still being running

after few cycles like this, all my threads are drained and my app dies

How can i cancel the running threads on the pool after the timeout has reached?
(without calling pool.shutdown())

***UPDATE****
inside the main thread i did a simple check as shown here

```
for (int i = TIME_OUT_SECONDS; i >= 0; i--) {
                unfinishedTasks = handleFutureTasks(unfinishedTasks, totalBatchSize);
                if(unfinishedTasks.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
                if(i==0) {
                    //handle cancelation of the tasks
                    for(CompletableFuture<ComplianceCandidate> task: unfinishedTasks) {
                        **task.cancel(true);**
                        log.error("Reached timeout on task, is canceled: {}", task.isCancelled());
                    }
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
```

What i see is that after few cycles, all the tasks complain about timeout...
in the first 1-2 cycles, i still get epected responses (while there are threads to process it)

i still feel that the thread pool is exhausted

Comment: It is possible, but unlikely, that the network threads are in uninterruptible sleep, in which it is not really possible to kill them. It would be worth checking that this not happening. htop and other similar tools can show if a thread is in uninterruptible sleep.

Comment: Even if the evaluation is hanging in an interruptible operation, you’re using the wrong tool for the job. Just consider the [the documentation of `CompletableFuture`’s `cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel(boolean)): “***Parameters**:
`mayInterruptIfRunning` - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.*” In other words, it doesn’t matter whether you use `cancel(true)` or `cancel(false)`, as `CompletableFuture` doesn’t support interruption at all.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said *without* calling `pool.shutDown`, but there is simply no other way. When you look at your stages though, they will run in either the thread that "appends" them (adding those `thenApply`) or a thread from that pool that you define. May be an example should make more sense.

```
public class SO64743332 {

    static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CompletableFuture<String> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbCall(), pool);

        //simulateWork(4);

        CompletableFuture<String> f2 = f1.thenApply(x -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return transformationOne(x);
        });

        CompletableFuture<String> f3 = f2.thenApply(x -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return transformationTwo(x);
        });

        f3.join();
    }

    private static String dbCall() {
        simulateWork(2);
        return "a";
    }

    private static String transformationOne(String input) {
        return input + "b";
    }

    private static String transformationTwo(String input) {
        return input + "b";
    }

    private static void simulateWork(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

They key point of the above code is this : `simulateWork(4);`. Run the code with it commented out and then uncomment it. See what thread is actually going to execute all those `thenApply`. It is either `main` or the *same* thread from the pool, meaning although you have a pool defined - it's only a single thread from that pool that will execute all those stages.

In this context, you could define a single thread executor (inside a method let's say) that will run all those stages. This way you could control when to call `shutDownNow` and potentially interrupt (if your code responds to interrupts) the running task. Here is a made-up example that simulates that:

```
public class SO64743332 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        execute();
    }


    public static void execute() {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        CompletableFuture<String> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> dbCall(), pool);
        CompletableFuture<String> cf2 = cf1.thenApply(x -> transformationOne(x));

        // give enough time for transformationOne to start, but not finish
        simulateWork(2);

        try {
            CompletableFuture<String> cf3 = cf2.thenApply(x -> transformationTwo(x))
                                               .orTimeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            cf3.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            pool.shutdownNow();
        }

    }

    private static String dbCall() {
        System.out.println("Started DB call");
        simulateWork(1);
        System.out.println("Done with DB call");
        return "a";
    }

    private static String transformationOne(String input) {
        System.out.println("Started work");
        simulateWork(10);
        System.out.println("Done work");
        return input + "b";
    }

    private static String transformationTwo(String input) {
        System.out.println("Started transformation two");
        return input + "b";
    }

    private static void simulateWork(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(seconds));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running this you should notice that `transformationOne` starts, but it is interrupted because of the `shutDownNow`.

The drawback of this should be obvious, every invocation of `execute` will create a new thread pool...